# Why do I not get the result back from my startActivityForResult?

Tags: android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I have one class `LogBeerActivity` that extends `AppCompatActivity` and has these two methods:

```
public void gotoAddBrewery(View view) {
    String breweryNameEntered = breweryTextView.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddBreweryActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRAS_ID_BREWERY_NAME, breweryNameEntered);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_BREWERY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG_LOG_BEER_ACTIVITY, "Got request result code: " + resultCode);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case ADD_BREWERY_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String breweryName = data.getStringExtra(AddBreweryActivity.BREWERY_NAME_CODE);
                breweryTextView.setText(breweryName);
            }
    }
}
```

The other class `AddBreweryActivity` also extends `AppCompatActivity` and it has this method called when its form with user input is submitted:

```
public void submitBrewery(View view) {
    EditText breweryLocationInput = findViewById(R.id.input_brewery_location);
    EditText breweryCountryInput = findViewById(R.id.input_brewery_country);
    if (breweryNameInput == null || breweryLocationInput == null || breweryCountryInput == null) {
        Log.e(TAG_ADD_BREWERY_ACTIVITY, "One of the inputs is null!");
        return;
    } else {
        String enteredBreweryName = breweryNameInput.getText().toString().trim();
        String enteredBreweryLocation = breweryLocationInput.getText().toString().trim();
        String enteredBreweryCountry = breweryCountryInput.getText().toString().trim();
        Log.d(TAG_ADD_BREWERY_ACTIVITY, "submitBeer clicked. Brewery: " + enteredBreweryName + " from: " + enteredBreweryLocation + " in: " + enteredBreweryCountry);
        if (!enteredBreweryName.isEmpty() && !enteredBreweryLocation.isEmpty() && !enteredBreweryCountry.isEmpty()) {
            NewBrewery newBrewery = new NewBrewery(enteredBreweryName, enteredBreweryLocation, enteredBreweryCountry);
            URL url = HttpHelper.getUrl(Constants.URL_BASE + Constants.URL_BREWERIES_PATH);
            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    HttpHelper.makeRequest(url, newBrewery, this);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG_ADD_BREWERY_ACTIVITY, "Error trying to submit new brewery: ", e);
                    return;
                } catch (HttpHelper.UserNotLoggedInException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG_ADD_BREWERY_ACTIVITY, "Error trying to submit new brewery: ", e);
                    return;
                }
            });
            thread.start();
            Intent resultIndent = new Intent();
            resultIndent.putExtra(BREWERY_NAME_CODE, newBrewery.getName());
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIndent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `onActivityResult` method never gets called, even though the flow between the two activities happens as expected.

**EDIT:** I've made a discovery. If I comment out the lines of code that do the HTTP request to my server (From the line starting with `URL url = ...` until and including the line starting with `thread.start();` then it works. Is it something to do with starting the new thread that messes things up? In fact, it's enough to just comment out the line that reads `thread.start();` and it works (except the http request isn't made, of course).

Comment: startActivityForResult imp. looks correct

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not get the result back"? Is `onActivityResult()` just not running? Or are you not getting the expected data there?

Comment: `onActivityResult` doesn't get called. The debug line isn't printed and it doesn't hit a breakpoint if I place one in there.

Comment: What is the value of `ADD_BREWERY_REQUEST_CODE`?

Comment: It used to be `1`, but as a test I've changed it to `111` in the latest version of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

though the implementation seems fine, It feels like that it's not going into the IF Condition. Try commenting out your code and only execute the setResult and see if it's calling the onActivityResult or not
e.g.

```
public void submitBrewery(View view) {
    Log.e(TAG,"Submitting setResult");
    Intent resultIndent = new Intent();
    resultIndent.putExtra(BREWERY_NAME_CODE, "BREWERY_NAME");
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIndent);
    finish();
}
```

---

Though I know your problem has been solved, I'm curious what happens if you try the following:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    HttpHelper.makeRequest(url, newBrewery, this);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG_ADD_BREWERY_ACTIVITY, "Error trying to submit new brewery: ", e);
                    return;
                } catch (HttpHelper.UserNotLoggedInException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG_ADD_BREWERY_ACTIVITY, "Error trying to submit new brewery: ", e);
                    return;
                }

                AddBreweryActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Intent resultIndent = new Intent();
                        resultIndent.putExtra(BREWERY_NAME_CODE, newBrewery.getName());
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIndent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            });
thread.start();
```

Comment: I could try that, but it definitely gets in there. I've had checkpoints in there that get hit, and also the HTTP requests go through fine.

Comment: Strangely, when I changed it to this I _do_ get the result back (onActivityResult is called). But I don't understand why (like I mentioned, the setResult and finish code is also reached in my version...

Comment: @SvendHansen, I've updated my answer and want you to try the code

Comment: Thank you, @Sahil! I'll try this out when I have time (might not be for a few days, as I'll be quite busy). Sounds like a good idea, though, as it would wait until the Http request has completed, before returning the result (and allows for dealing with an error from the server instead) :)

Comment: Yes, this works. While you didn't directly point out the original problem (how could you when I hadn't even shared that code), your suggestion did lead me to discover it, and your second suggestion is exactly what I need to do to be able to wait for the success of the request. So I've awarded you the bounty as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry people, but it turned out that I was just being an idiot...

In my HttpHelper.makeRequest method I'd put in a "hack" at some point (maybe a year ago, when I was last working on the project) that did:

```
LoginActivity.startLoginActivity(context);
```

Which in turn did:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Which of course would derail the whole returning with the result, but it wouldn't be obvious, as it would end you up on the same page. The reason for the hack was that it was a simple way to get the updated data back from the server after the POST... if I comment out that line in the HttpHelper, it all works fine (except I have to update the local data to contain the new brewery, but that's a different task).

I'm not sure if I should delete this whole question, as it's unlikely useful to anyone else...?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new Intent object at AddBreweryActivity. It is normal to not calling the activity result.
You should get the current intent for the notify on result which activity send the intent object.
If you change this code line

```
Intent resultIndent = new Intent();
```

with this one,

```
Intent resultIndent = getIntent();
```

it's going to notify `onActivityResult` of activity where getIntent() is coming from which is LogBeerActivity.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't seem to fix it. It still behaves the same. Do you think it would make a difference if I posted the entire two classes?

Comment: Also, examples I've seen seem to do `new Intent()`. However, they often do it in their onCreate, like here:
https://www.codexpedia.com/android/using-startactivityforresult-in-android/
Where as I do it in a method called when a form is submitted. Can't really do it in onCreate, as I wouldn't have gotten the data to pass back from the user yet at that point... :P